# Firebase Google Sign-In gets stuck on /__/auth/handler route

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm following the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) to try and add Google sign-in to a project that uses. firebase auth.

- I'm running the code in an iframe (as it's an Airtable app). Could this be the issue?
- I have enabled Google Sign-In in the firebase console.
- `data-fetcher-dev.firebaseapp.com` is included in Firebase authorized domains.

My code:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyCp8i_9lHCyLOREMIPSUM21342xXmb0F0Y',
authDomain: 'data-fetcher-dev.firebaseapp.com',
projectId: 'data-fetcher-dev',
});

const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

googleProvider.addScope('profile');
googleProvider.addScope('email');

...

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider);
      console.log('result: ', result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    }
  };
```

`signInWithGoogle` is called when a button is pressed. A new tab opens and I am able to select a Google account/ sign in to one:

[image]

After selecting an account I am redirected to a URL like `https://data-fetcher-dev.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?state=LONG_TOKEN_VALUE&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=3&prompt=consent` and **the page just loads forever**:

[image]

I am using firebase hosting so there is an empty project at `https://data-fetcher-dev.firebaseapp.com`. Do I need to implement a backend route at `/__/auth/handler`? I thought Firebase was supposed to handle that for me, as they do not mention it in the docs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open the console and check for any errors?

Comment: Yeah, there are no console errors

Comment: Hey Andy, did you ever resolve this? Seeing the same issue...

Comment: I never figured it out although looks like a couple of others have below

Answer (score 7):

Adding onto what others mentioned since it took me forever to sort all of this out, as it had nothing to do with the custom domain itself or the authorized domain settings in GCP or Firebase.

In `vite-plugin-pwa` you can pass workbox settings under `navigateFallbackDenylist` which accepts an array of RegExp:

```
const pwaOptions: Partial<VitePWAOptions> = {
  base: "/",
  manifest: {
     // ..
  },
  workbox: {
    navigateFallbackDenylist: [/__/], // Allows firebase auth routes to pass through service worker
  },
};
```

Comment: For Quasar v1 (2023), this answer, in combination with the answer below, made it for me. You may have to edit both your register-service-worker.js and your workboxOptions options.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75584521/418974

Comment: I upgraded a Vue2 app from Vue CLI to Vite and this approach solved it. My config looks different to yours though, so I might post another answer

Comment: @ChristianBonato I'm having the same issue with my quasar app but does that mean I have to run the app in PWA mode? I'm currently have it at SPA mode.

Comment: @TronyTr workbox and thus manifest are intended to be used in PWA mode. The service worker is usually used to detect a new release of your app. You can develop locally in SPA and then build a PWA. Checkout Lighthouse in Chrome Dev Tools to check your PWA compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

I was just facing this, though with a custom domain and using the `signInWithRedirect` method.

We noticed that the auth handler url `our.custom.domain/__/auth/handler` was serving html from our site, when we expected to see something from google's auth handling service.

The issue was caused by our service worker, which was handling the request. By poking a hole through the service worker's registered routes, we were able to resolve the hanging `__/auth/handler` route.

We use workbox in our service-worker.

```
// Poke a hole through the service worker for the firebase auth handlers.
registerRoute(({ url }) => url.pathname.startsWith('/__/'), new NetworkFirst());
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded a Vue2 app from Vue CLI to Vite and swapped `"register-service-worker"` for `"vite-plugin-pwa"` and hit this problem in production. I could see in the Chrome developer network tab that the "__/auth/handler?" URL was being served from the servive worker.

I followed @Darren Segal's answer, adding the option to my Vite PWA config.

vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite"
import {VitePWA} from 'vite-plugin-pwa'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        VitePWA({
            // Allow Firebase auth routes to pass through service worker
            workbox: {navigateFallbackDenylist: [/__/]},
        }),
```

The only part I don't understand is why this wasn't happening in `"register-service-worker"` too. I can't see any equivalent routing exception in my old app setup.